# Blazor Server: authenticating against Identity Server 4 and using cookies for local authentication

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to build a server side Blazor app that lets users signin against Identity Server 4 and uses Cookies for handling local authorization. Here's the code for my current setup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                               options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                           })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc",
                          options => {
                              Configuration.GetSection("OidcSettings").Bind(options);

                              // remove unecessary claims
                              options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("amr", "sub");
                              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                                                                                                    NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
                                                                                                };
                          });
```

I want to use the nameidentifier claim as the user's name and I was under the impression that the previous mapping should take care of that. Unfortunately, it's not working. Here's some demo code:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<AuthorizeView>
  <NotAuthorized>
    <form method="post" action="/Account/Login">
      <button>Iniciar</button>
    </form>
  </NotAuthorized>
  <Authorized>
    <h1>Hi, @ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
    <h1>Hi, @(GetUsernameAsync().Result)!</h1>
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private async Task<string> GetUsernameAsync() {
      var user1 = ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
      var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
      var user = authState.User;

      if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
            return user.Identity.Name;
      }

      return "Nop";
    }
}
```

In both cases, the user's name is always set to null. Here's what I'm getting from the debugger:

[image: User Identity from aspnet core context]

There are a couple of things I'm not getting:

1. Why am I getting this authentication type? SHouldn't it be cookies ou application cookie (or something like that)?
2. Why hasn't the name claim been change to name identifier?

I'm surely missing something, but I'm not sure on what...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after several tests, I've finally managed to get it working. I've started using the sub claim as my user's username. I've had to change a couple of things on the OpenId Connect setup:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc",
                  options => {
                      Configuration.GetSection("OidcSettings").Bind(options);

                      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                                                                                            NameClaimType = "sub"
                                                                                        };
                  });
```